# Footnotes within cryptocode's procedure command appears twice

Tags: footnotes

When a footnote is used in the second parameter of the `\procedure` command of the [cryptocode](https://ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode?lang=en) package as in the following MWE,

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{cryptocode}
  \begin{document}
  \procedure{\hspace{1cm}}{
    \footnote{}
  }
\end{document}
```

, the footnote is rendered twice as shown in the following picture.
[image]

I would like to figure out why that is and how to prevent it.

Comment: The common dance with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{...}` to work around most footnote  problems doesn't work at all, it just makes a greater mess.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after being annoyed with this long enough to take deep dive, I have figured out the cause and a (questionable) way to hack around it.

The root cause here is not so much the cryptocode package itself, in fact I'm fairly certain, the fact that footnotes can be added directly to a piece of pseudocode is an accidental effect of the use of minipages.

The actual root cause of the double footnote is that the pseudocode is typeset in an `flalign*` environment. The problem actually also occurs with regular `align*` environments within minipages. The following example has the same issue.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    \begin{align*}
      \footnote{}
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Of course this isn't much of an issue because one rarely wants to use footnotes within equations.

It is possible to make the \footnotemark, \footnotetext dance work, but for that we need to

1. Patch one of the internal cryptocode commands.
2. Define an equivalent command to \footnotemark for mpfootnote.

The first part of that can be achieved by

```
\define@key{pseudocode}{foot}[]{\newcommand*\@pseudocodefoot{#1}}
\apptocmd{\pc@display@pseudocode}{\@ifundefined{@pseudocodefoot}{}{\@pseudocodefoot}}{}{}
```

Which allows us to specify some additional code using key "foot" to put between the end of the flalign* and the end of the minipage.

To define an equivalent to \footnotemark for minipages, we can modify the original \footnotemark code as

```
\def\mpfootnotemark{%
   \@ifnextchar[\@xmpfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
      \@footnotemark}}
\def\@xmpfootnotemark[#1]{%
   \begingroup
      \c@mpfootnote #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark}
```

Overall, this means our MWE is now

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{cryptocode}

\makeatletter
\define@key{pseudocode}{foot}[]{\newcommand*\@pseudocodefoot{#1}}
\apptocmd{\pc@display@pseudocode}{\@ifundefined{@pseudocodefoot}{}{\@pseudocodefoot}}{}{}

\def\mpfootnotemark{%
   \@ifnextchar[\@xmpfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
      \@footnotemark}}
\def\@xmpfootnotemark[#1]{%
   \begingroup
      \c@mpfootnote #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\procedure[foot={\footnotetext{}}]{\hspace{1cm}}{
  \text{\mpfootnotemark}
}
\end{document}
```

Which works like we want it to.

[image]